# Missing captioned images feature in TinyMCE and Plone5

Tags: tinymce, plone, caption, plone-5.x

I'm missing the function to enable captioned images in TinyMCE/Plone5. It was possible to enable that in the control panel with Plone4 (https://plone.org/documentation/manual/plone-4-user-manual/using-tinymce-as-visual-editor/images).

Now I'm using the new Plone5rc3 with TinyMCE 1.4.3, but the properties of TinyMCE in the control panel don't have the needed checkbox.

Does anybody know how to get that?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: are you sure you are using tinymce 1.4.3 and not tinymce 4.3.1?

Comment: Afaik you should no install Products.TinyMCE anymore. the tinymce widget is now in plone.app.widgets.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear expression, I use the integrated Products.TinyMCE from Plone, and got the version number from the versions.cfg file (http://dist.plone.org/release/5.0rc3/versions.cfg).

Comment: Well, it's may be there for compatibility reasons..

Comment: @Mathias: hasn't it been merged into base CMFPlone? p.a.widgets 2.0.1 (the one that ships with plain Plone5) is practically empty.

Comment: sounds like a feature that is missing. File a bug report. This was supported in Plone 4.x and was probably forgotten in the plone 5 tinymce upgrade.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So here's an answer in parts: you need several things for the captions to work:

- Your `<img>` tags need to have the class `captioned`. I still need to find a good way to do that. The image picker will remove all other classes everytime you open it, so I guess a good way would be to change the classes that are added by the inline/left/right selection, but I've not easily found where those are defined.
- You need the output filter, but fortunately, that is still there. However, the filter wants to see an `IImageCaptioningEnabler`, which is essentially a flag to turn the captioning mechanism on, and the old editors used to have that and currently, nothing in standard Plone does provide such a beast. If you're comfortable with add-on development, the class you want is

```
from plone.outputfilters.filters.resolveuid_and_caption import IImageCaptioningEnabler
from zope.interface import implements
class CaptioningAlwaysEnabled(object):
    implements(IImageCaptioningEnabler)

    available = True
```

with corresponding `configure.zcml` stanza

```
<utility factory=".resolveuid_and_caption.CaptioningAlwaysEnabled"
         name="plone5-captions-always-enabled"
         zcml:condition="have plone-5" />
```

(you can tell I patched `buildout-cache/plone.outputfilters-2.1-py2.7.egg/plone/outputfilters/filters/configure.zcml` and `resolveuid_and_caption.py` to include that, but of course, you shouldn't do that.)

If you're not comfortable with add-on development, you could, bizarrely enough, see if another editor provides that global switch, you don't need to have it set as your editor or the default editor. (`Products.kupu` would, but it doesn't install in 5.0. `collective.ckeditor` might, I can't try that right now due to missing dependencies.)

So, summary: no, you can't easily turn it on; you can turn it on with a bit of hacking; and if you [file it as a feature request](https://plone.org/documentation/faq/i-think-ive-found-a-bug-in-plone.-where-should-i-report-it), it's the kind of thing that takes about fifteen minutes to fix for somebody who knows their way around the code.